# How to join two tables, with distinct columns on either side?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables I'm trying to join to produce a unique set of data for a third table, but having trouble doing this properly.

- The `left` table has an `id` field, as well as a common join field (`a`).
- The `right` table has the common join field (`a`), and another distinct field (`b`)

I'm trying to extract a result-set of `id` and `b`, where neither `id` nor `b` are duplicated.

I have an SQL fiddle set up: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/208de/3/0

The ideal results should be:

```
id | b
---+---
1  | 1
2  | 2
3  | 3
```

Each `id` and `b` value appears only once (it's only coincidence they match here, that can't be assumed always).

Thanks

Comment: Something's fishy. Check this out http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_distinct and try the following query `SELECT DISTINCT City, Country FROM Customers;
`

Comment: They don't match in your SQLFiddle. If you join by `a` you'll end up with a cross join. So every value from `id` joined with every value from `b`. Furthermore, in your sqlFiddle, you have a GROUP BY, but you only include `id` in there. That's a recipe for disaster. MySQl will just choose the first `b` value it finds for each distinct `id` it comes across, which is definitely bad and wrong and disgusting and I don't like MySQl because it allows things like that.

Comment: Just to elaborate, your join on `a` will grab the first record from `left` and then match the `a` value of `1` to each record where `a` is `1` in `right`. That's three records. Then it will move to your next record in `left` where `a` is again `1` and it will find, again, three matching records in `right` where `a` is `1`. Then again for the third record. Your result set will have 9 records. You end up with a cartesian product ([sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/208de/44)). What logic would use to get from those 9 records to your 3 records in your desired output?

Comment: Thanks for your answers, guys. I am aware of how cross-joins, etc, work and why MySQL is coming up with the results it does... I'm looking for solutions as to how to achieve my desired result. The fiddle was set up only as example to indicate the issue, I'm not presenting it as a solution - obviously!

Answer (score -1):

What about a CTE along with a DISTINCT, Would that work?

```
WITH
  cte1 (ID, B)
  AS
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT Table1.ID
    FROM Table1
    WHERE Table1.ID IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY Table1.ID
  )
SELECT DISTINCT
  Table2.b
FROM Table2 AS sp
  INNER JOIN cte1 AS ts
    ON sp.b <> ts.ID
ORDER BY ts.ID DESC
```

Comment: That only ensures the first column is distinct, it doesn't ensure the second is distinct